# How do I upload a file to Amazon S3 using a lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I want to run a function in Lambda in python that takes a file in my local directory and updates to Amazon S3. I made this but the file is not being uploaded. What's wrong?

```
import json
import logging
import boto3
import os

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    file_name = "/Users/thesadmermaid/Downloads/grafico.csv"
    bucket = "Transitory-lambda-data"
 
def upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name=None):  

if object_name is None:
    object_name = os.path.basename(file_name)

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
response = s3_client.upload_file(file_name, bucket, object_name)

return response
```

Comment: AWS Lambda functions run in a server in an Amazon data center. How is it going to have access to your local file? Also, when things like this aren't working **please** include the error message you are getting as part of your question.

Comment: Yes, the lambda function is like it's own Docker container essentially (runs on Amazon Linux 1/2). it won't have access to your local drive. If you're trying to read from that exact file path, it won't work on lambda.

Comment: But one thing it *can* do is read the CSV file from S3 - assuming you uploaded it from your local machine. I guess tha possibly might be the question you had.

Comment: That code needs to run on your local machine because only there does it have access to your local file system.

Comment: Please fix your code's indentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Python to upload a file on your local desktop, you cannot use a Lambda function. It has no access to your desktop as the Lambda function runs in the cloud. You need to write a script that runs on your local desktop, can access your desktop files and then uses the **Python Amazon S3 API** to perform a **PutObject** operation.